# How to get an autostart application to start minimized upon login?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde

I'm running `Ubuntu` with `Gnome` but in order to install `KMouseTool` I had to install `KDE` also.

Whenever I start up Ubuntu, **KMousetool**, which I've set as an *`autostart`* application, ***starts up in a fully maximized window***.

If I run it in ***KDE*** there seems to be various ***window appearance options*** I can set for the application. But in ***Gnome***, these don't seem to be present.

*`Is there a setting I could define for the application to make it run as a minimized/hidden window upon login?`*

It's annoying to have to manually minimize the app every time I login.

Comment: Nice formatting :)

Comment: Just doing my best to make the text easily eyeball-scannable. I'm glad you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These window behaviors are managed by Metacity I believe, you can use [**Devil's Pie**](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) to do what you want though.

> A window-matching utility, inspired by
>   Sawfish's "Matched Windows" option and
>   the lack of the functionality in
>   Metacity. Metacity lacking window
>   matching is not a bad thing — Metacity
>   is a lean window manager, and window
>   matching does not have to be a window
>   manager task.
>
> Devil's Pie can be configured to
>   detect windows as they are created,
>   and match the window to a set of
>   rules. If the window matches the
>   rules, it can perform a series of
>   actions on that window. For example, I
>   can make all windows created by X-Chat
>   appear on all workspaces, and the main
>   Gkrellm1 window does not appear in the
>   pager or task list.

Comment: This looks like it will do the job. I'm still puzzling over ksystraycmd which autostarts kmousetool. There's a "--hidden" option you can pass to this command but it's not taking effect when I do: "ksystraycmd --hidden /usr/bin/kmousetool. I'll try Devil's Pie. Thanks.

Comment: Woohoo! It worked! Wish I could vote you up a few more times.